# Can bytearray values be overridden?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm just making my first steps in python, and this is my first stackoverflow question ever :)

I've been trying to convert a string of hex numbers to a bytearray, xor each byte, and convert back to a hex string. The xor works fine, but when I convert it back to a string, it goes back to the previous values.
What am I doing wrong?

```
string="4353417B"

arr = bytearray.fromhex(string) #convert string into bytearray

for i in arr:
        i = i^0x43;
        print(hex(i))

xor_string = arr.hex() #convert bytearray back into string
print(xor_string)
```

Output:
0x0
0x10
0x2
0x38
4353417b

Answer (score 1):

The `i` in your loop isn't tied to the `bytearray`; it's constructed from it, but modifying it doesn't change the value in the `bytearray` any more than modifying an `int` received as an argument modifies the caller's `int`.

If you want to modify the values in place, you have to reassign the index in the `bytearray`, e.g.:

```
for index, value in enumerate(arr):
    arr[index] = value ^ 0x43
```

I named the unpacked variables `index` and `value` for clarity, but most people tend to abbreviate to `i` and `x` or `val` (or use a useful name for `value`) in real code.

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a value **copied** from the array - it does not reference back to the array. So here you get `i`, modify it, and then discard the value once the block ends.

Instead, you can use the subscript operator (`[]`) to refer to the element in the array:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] = arr[i] ^0x43
```

or, more elegantly:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] ^= 0x43
```